# Laravel Jessenger mongodb, can't change nested child format

Tags: json, mongodb, laravel

am new with mongodb and i have the following issue with laravel using jessenger.
I have this collection structure's

```
{
  "_id": "597a1e5db7893325c3557152",
  "name": "Idalio",
  "age": "20",
  "created_at":"2017-07-27 04:00:01",
  "updated_at":"2017-07-27 17:09:49",
  "child": [{
    "name": "childName",
    "age": "5",
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "597a1e5db7893325c3557153"
    },
    "created_at": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1501175389000"
        }
    },
    "updated_at": {
        "$date": {
            "$numberLong": "1501175389000"
        }
    }
  }]
```

}

In the nested child "_id", "created_at" and "updated_at" the format of these attributes it's different from the parent. All i need is the child has the same format as the parent because these data must be readed from an old PDA and these doesnt support this format ... In my model i have the following

```
public function child(){
    return $this->embedsMany('App\Models\Child');
}
```

And for last in mongodb the parent and child dates and "_id" are the same format. I dont know why child object is coming with these format. some one can help me to work this out? :)

Comment: In fact the "child" entries here are actually in the **correct** format and using the native types, where as your "parent" entries are **incorrect** and are "stringifying" the values that "should" in fact be stored as BSON types. So really it's the "parent" that needs to be fixed here. Strings are not good for this data, as they have limitations and take a lot more storage as well.

Comment: Ok, i get it and you're right. But i need the child has the parent format not only the dates, because they must be readed from an old device than doesnt support the child format

Comment: Not really much of an excuse. Proposing "I want to break new code and persist the problems of old code" is generally not that productive. It might get tasks checked off an agile board, but it's really only adding work to do later. Better to raise the issue and fix the existing problems.

Comment: It's not an excuse. This must be readed for a windows ce 3.5  device which its extremly limited. And i can't change it because not depende of mi. I  would use a android device instead of that but cant be that way. So, the better way is change the json format.

Answer (score -1):

May be in Model use Accessors & Mutators

```
protected $dates = ['date'];
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators